# Compiling using gfortran in Mac

Tags: macos, debugging, fortran, gfortran

So bear with me as I am very new to coding. I'm trying to compile a Fortran file but I keep getting this issue in my terminal.
I am using GNU Fortran (GCC) 9.2.0 and I believe I have all other prerequisites updated Xcode and atom. Appreciate any and all help spent went way too long just to say hello world.

```
% gfortran -o myprog hello.f90
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Not sure hiw you installed your compiler, but if you didn't use **homebrew**, I would recommend uninstalling your `gfortran` and installing the **homebrew** one with `brew install gcc`

Comment: ... and if you had installed with homebrew, the install  make break if you upgrade the OS. In that case, `brew rebuild gcc` or `brew reinstall gcc`

Comment: If you need a fast track to `gfortran` you can use `Docker` based approach: https://www.owsiak.org/learning-coarrys-on-macos-using-docker-based-installation/ - if you are looking for a stable env. (native one), take a look here: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-8-3-0/ and here: https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/